# Connecting an Ionic app to an existing database

Tags: ionic-framework, silex

I have an existing database that I want to connect to an Ionic app I've made. Ive seen people recommend Silex to make a RESTful api but I have no idea how to do so, and the tutorials I've seen use new apps, not existing ones. I just want to be pointed in the right direction since its all a little overwhelming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to know how to make api calls from ionic to your restful server or do you want to make restful apis.

Comment: If you are using php I would recommend slim framework. Try googling "restful server using slim"